# Why are my navigation buttons incorrectly aligned inside of their list?

Tags: html, css

For some reason, whenever my webpage is within a certain size, the words within the navigation bar move to a different location, and I am not sure why.

To see what I'm talking about, take a look at my code [**on jsFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/KyleTheBoss95/t7sunb6j/). 
Stretch the results window all the way to the left and watch the `li` buttons.

HTML:

```
<head>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" >
</head>

<header class="row">
        <a name="home"></a>
        <div class="container">
            <figure class="col-lg-12"><a href="index.html"><img src="assets/karate-kick.png" height="100" width="400" alt="karate kick"></a></figure>
            <nav>
                <ul class="col-lg-7">
                    <li class="col-md-2"><a href="#about">About</a></li>
                    <li class="col-md-2"><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </div>
    </header>
```

CSS:

```
nav ul.col-lg-7 {
    text-decoration:none;
    float:right;
    position: relative;
}

nav ul li.col-md-2 {
    list-style-type: none;
    font-size: 2rem;
    background-color: white;
    color:black;
    border: 3px outset lightgray;
    margin: 8rem 0 1rem 1rem;
    float:left;
    bottom: 5rem;
    border-radius: 25px;    
    text-align: center;
    box-shadow: 100px black;
    padding: 0 5rem;
}

nav ul li.col-md-2:active {
    border: 3px inset lightgrey;
    position: relative;
}

nav ul li.col-md-2:hover {
    background-color:yellow;
}

header div.container {
    background-color: red;
}
div figure {
    top: 6rem;
}
```

Comment: Put margin: 8rem 0 1rem 1rem; into the nav ul.col-lg-7 declaration

Comment: In some way **jeff** is right: [see here the modified version of your JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/LoicMars/t7sunb6j/2/)

Comment: @Kyle checkout my answer

Comment: I appreciate you trying to help, but the modified JsFiddle doesn't fix my problem. I get the problem because I am trying to make my website responsive, and when in fullscreen, it looks fine. It is just when the browser window is a certain width. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 0):

Do you care about the mobile version of the site? If you don't, I have just what you are looking for:

Try changing this:

```
<li class="col-md-2"><a href="#about">About</a></li>
<li class="col-md-2"><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
```

To this:

```
<li class="col-md-2"><a href="#about" class="navLinks1">About</a></li>
<li class="col-md-2"><a href="#contact" class="navLinks2">Contact</a></li>
```

Then add this to the top of your CSS:

```
.navLinks{
  position:relative;
  right:28px;
}

.navLinks2{
  position:relative;
  right:33px;
}
```

This makes it so the text is centered correctly, but on the mobile site, not so much.

Comment: Thank you for trying to help, but my problem is from me working on the mobile site haha. The site looks fine when in fullscreen on desktop, but it is when it gets to tablet screen width that it starts messing up. But the confusing part is that it works on phone width screens, just not tablet width. I think it is about 1000 pixels to 1200 pixels that it looks weird. Sorry for any confusion or lack of clarity.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was you haven't attached your bootstrap, jQuery CDN's properly attach these CDN's to your `<head>` tag.That's why those buttons were messed up.

```
<head>      
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
```

Here's the [**CODEPEN**](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/yOvaKL) example.

**EDIT:**

If those Bootstrap files are located locally.then try to add the following structure, because looks like you haven't properly added jQuery reference.

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
      <head>
        <title>Bootstrap 101 Template</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <!-- Bootstrap -->
        <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
      </head>
      <body>

<header class="row">
        <a name="home"></a>
        <div class="container">
            <figure class="col-lg-12"><a href="index.html"><img src="assets/karate-kick.png" height="100" width="400" alt="karate kick"></a></figure>
            <nav>
                <ul class="col-lg-7">
                    <li class="col-md-2"><a href="#about">About</a></li>
                    <li class="col-md-2"><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </div>
    </header>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>
        <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
      </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Oh, in my code, I downloaded the bootstrap files onto my computer and added them as a local file. I only linked them like that in my question because I was attempting to help whoever helped me get the exact problem that I was encountering. I apologize for the confusion.

Comment: @KyleTheBoss95 So where are those bootstrap files located?

Comment: I downloaded them from the bootstrap website and have them linked locally on my computer. Also, because this is a small project and I am still learning Javascript, I haven't added any jQuery to the site quite yet. It isn't so much of a linking problem (everything works fine in different screen sizes, it is just when the browser width is between 1000 and 1200 pixels in width), but it appears to be more of a CSS styling problem that I can't figure out. When I publish the website, if you are still interested, I will link you to the site so you can see what I mean.